# Systemd won't turn numlock off

Tags: shutdown, systemd, numlock

I HATE the fact that my numlock light stays on after shutdown!

I prepared a unit file like this one

```
[Unit]
Description=Turn Num Lock off before shutdown
RequiresMountsFor=/ #dunno if needed, just in case

[Service]
ExecStop=/usr/local/sbin/numlock.sh
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

And I can tell for sure that it works because inside the script there isn't only the numlock command but also a "touch /home/user/TEST" that does appear when I turn the system on

the commands I tried to turn off the light are numlockx, xset and xdotool : all three of them work perfectly when the system is on: any hint about what is wrong?

Comment: There is nothing wrong. I have used Ubuntu since v14 and the NumLock light has always remained on. If it troubles you that much, turn it off before you turn the machine off or kill the machine completely rather than just use shut down.

Comment: What dsstorefile1 says makes sense! Any suggestion to work around this issue? I know I can turn it off manually but I forget about it, even if I made a shortcut to avoid the issue, so I'd love to automate the process

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested, the command inside the numlock.sh script was wrong, probably because before the shutdown you can't rely on a X based command

A script like this works perfectly

```
#!/bin/bash

for tty in /dev/tty?; do /usr/bin/setleds -D +num < "$tty"; done
```

Actually I changed the UNIT file to simplify, it won't need a script now.

```
[Unit]
Description=Turn off numlock at shutdown

[Service]
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c "for tty in /dev/tty?; do /usr/bin/setleds -D +num < "$tty"; done"

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```